# Install via cli but exclude some core modules

Tags: module, installation, magento2.2

I'm installing Magento 2.2 via command line using

> php bin/magento setup:install --backend-frontname="my-admin-value" --db-host=my.db.host --db-name=dbname --db-user=dbuser --db-password=dbpass --base-url="http://example.com" --language=en_US --timezone="Europe/Bucharest" --currency="EUR" --use-secure=1 --base-url-secure="https://example.com/" --admin-user=adminUser --admin-password=AdminPass --admin-email="me@example.com" --admin-firstname=John --admin-lastname=Doe --use-rewrites=1

And it works fine, but now I want to install it and skip the at least 2 core modules because I don't need them. Let's say they are `Magento_Bundle` and `Magento_BundleImportExport`.
(Ignore the fact that there might be dependent module on these. I don't care for now. Let's say I can disable the modules when installing via UI wizard).
How can I do that? Is it even possible? Is there a parameter I need to pass to the command?
I've tried running the command with `-h` but nothing comes up related to modules.

Comment: I am always installing Magento 2 via meta package via **composer**, and those packages/modules are in the `composer.json` so it does not seem to me that you can prevent them from installing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the output of `bin/magento help setup:install`. There are arguments for modules to enable or disable during installation:

```
--enable-modules[=ENABLE-MODULES]     List of comma-separated module names. That must be included during installation. Available magic param "all".
--disable-modules[=DISABLE-MODULES]   List of comma-separated module names. That must be avoided during installation. Available magic param "all".
```

Comment: ah. this was added for 2.3. I asked the question for 2.2. But I'll take it. Time to upgrade anyway. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Since all the modules are separate composer packages, I think you can disable them in `composer.json`. What I will describe is not a good solution, and it is kind of a hack.

First of all, I have installed Magento 2 with the following command,

```
composer create-project --repository-url=https://repo.magento.com/ magento/project-community-edition magento2.2
```

Secondly, I have removed modules you mentioned from vendor directory via the following command.

```
rm -Rf vendor/magento/module-bundle*
```

Then, I have added the following part into `composer.json` right after the **require** field.

```
"replace": {
    "magento/module-bundle": "100.2.0",
    "magento/module-bundle-import-export": "100.2.0"
},
```

So, this will say composer that those packages are already provided by your application. As a result, composer will not bother to install them again, since it is trusting what you say (We lied :().

After that you can run `composer install` or `composer update` again, and you won't see these packages in your vendor directory.

**The final version of my `composer.json` file**

```
{
    "name": "magento/project-community-edition",
    "description": "eCommerce Platform for Growth (Community Edition)",
    "type": "project",
    "version": "2.2.0",
    "license": [
        "OSL-3.0",
        "AFL-3.0"
    ],
    "require": {
        "magento/product-community-edition": "2.2.0",
        "composer/composer": "@alpha"
    },
    "replace": {
        "magento/module-bundle": "100.2.0",
        "magento/module-bundle-import-export": "100.2.0"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "phpunit/phpunit": "~6.2.0",
        "squizlabs/php_codesniffer": "3.0.1",
        "phpmd/phpmd": "@stable",
        "pdepend/pdepend": "2.5.0",
        "friendsofphp/php-cs-fixer": "~2.1.1",
        "lusitanian/oauth": "~0.8.10",
        "sebastian/phpcpd": "2.0.4"
    },
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "Magento\\Framework\\": "lib/internal/Magento/Framework/",
            "Magento\\Setup\\": "setup/src/Magento/Setup/",
            "Magento\\": "app/code/Magento/"
        },
        "psr-0": {
            "": [
                "app/code/"
            ]
        },
        "files": [
            "app/etc/NonComposerComponentRegistration.php"
        ],
        "exclude-from-classmap": [
            "**/dev/**",
            "**/update/**",
            "**/Test/**"
        ]
    },
    "autoload-dev": {
        "psr-4": {
            "Magento\\Sniffs\\": "dev/tests/static/framework/Magento/Sniffs/",
            "Magento\\Tools\\": "dev/tools/Magento/Tools/",
            "Magento\\Tools\\Sanity\\": "dev/build/publication/sanity/Magento/Tools/Sanity/",
            "Magento\\TestFramework\\Inspection\\": "dev/tests/static/framework/Magento/TestFramework/Inspection/",
            "Magento\\TestFramework\\Utility\\": "dev/tests/static/framework/Magento/TestFramework/Utility/"
        }
    },
    "minimum-stability": "stable",
    "repositories": [
        {
            "type": "composer",
            "url": "https://repo.magento.com/"
        }
    ],
    "extra": {
        "magento-force": "override"
    }
}
```

**EDIT 1:**
Actually, this method is used in the [official Magento repository](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.2-develop/composer.json). But they are providing those modules in the `app/code` directory. The only difference that you won't :).

Comment: This seems to work. But It skips the dependencies check. For example I was able to install magento without the bundle module but the msrp module depende on it. I don't know how this will impact me in the future.  I'm kind of scared to take this approach on long term. Anyway, I will investigate further and come back with results.

Comment: Ok. I got some results fast. I cannot run `setup:di:compile`. I get an error `Invalid Factory for nonexistent class Magento\Bundle\Api\Data\OptionInterface`. this is a result of the skipped dependency check. So it works in theory, but it's a risky way to do it. If you don't know what you are disabling you can easily get into trouble.

Answer (score 1):

Magento CLI comes with the module:status command which lists the statuses of existing modules. If you run it before installation you'll see that all the modules are enabled. Now, run module:disable passig the list of modules to disable. Run setup:install command after that.

Comment: This kind of works. The draw back is that I have to add the `app/etc/config.xml` upfront with all the modules and disable them one by one. The good part is that when disabling the module there is a check for dependencies and I know if I can disable it or not.